# What do these fields mean in Wireshark?

Tags: wireshark

What does the following mean in the info section of wireshark?

```
Source    Client
Destination Server
Protocol  HTTP   
Length    522
Info      522 GET /intl/en/images/logo.gif HTTP/1.1
```

More specifically, the client sends out a new request, which occurs automatically without any action by the user.  Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bog standard HTTP GET request, asking the server for the file `/intl/en/images/logo.gif`.  As for why it happens, you'll have to ask the developers of the mystery application you don't mention.